# Why is the power set always closed under complementation and unions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a set *S*, its power set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ always forms a sigma algebra (I read this in Casella & Berger). That is, the power set contains as an element *S* itself (which the power set clearly does, I have no problems with that), but also:

1. The power set must be closed under complementation: $$A \in \mathcal{P}(S) \implies A^c \in \mathcal{P}(S),$$
2. and the power set must be closed under countable unions:
   $$A_1, A_2, ... \in \mathcal{P}(S) \implies \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in \mathcal{P}(S). $$

However, this was not proven but only shown anecdotally by writing out the power set of the set $S = \{1,2,3\}$. While I certainly believe that this is true (it makes sense intuitively), I am having trouble understanding *why* it is true, much less proving that it is true. So, why does the power set have these properties?

Comment: Any subset of $S$ is in the power set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complement here is the relative complement in $S$:

$$A^c=S\setminus A=\{s\in S:s\notin A\}\,.$$

By definition this is a subset of $S$ and is therefore an element of $\wp(S)$.

Similarly, if $A_n\in\wp(S)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, let $A=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}A_n$. Then $x\in A$ if and only if $x\in A_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z^+$: every element of $A$ is an element of at least one $A_n$. And every $A_n$ is a subset of $S$, so every element of an $A_n$ is an element of $S$. Now put the pieces together: every element of $A$ is an element of $S$. That’s exactly what it means to say that $A\subseteq S$, i.e., that $A\in\wp(S)$.

Comment: Duh, thank you. I was definitely overthinking this one. But I really appreciate your explanation.

Comment: @wz-billings: You’re welcome.

Answer (score -1):

These follow by definitions.

$A^c = \{b \in S| b\not \in A\} \subset \{b\in S\} = S$.  So $A^c \in P(S) =\{K\subset A\}$.

$\cup_{i= 1}^\infty A_i = \{b \in A_i$ for some $A_i\subset S\} \subset \{b\in S\} = S$.  So $\cup_{i= 1}^\infty A_i  \in P(S) =\{K\subset A\}$.

That's it.  It's *just* definitions.